# Download stats of file hosted at a domain other than my website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, awstats, nearlyfreespeech

I'm publicly sharing an .ics file in my Dropbox (free hosting) and want to track it's use by my community.

Dropbox has no way of doing this, so I've setup **AWStats** on a static page at NearlyFreeSpeech.net with the intention of stealth redirecting from http://www.mydomain.com/files/calendar.ics to https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/XXXXXXX/calendar.ics.

(a) my **.htaccess** redirect won't work:

```
RewriteRule /files/calendar.ics https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/XXXXXXX/calendar.ics [PT]
```

(b) What section can I add to my nfsn-awstats.conf (analogous to awstats.config) to track the use of my redirect (#downloads_from_unique_IP_addresses and #downloads).

Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, how could I track #downloads_from_unique_IP_addresses and #downloads if I hosted the .ics at my domain directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try without leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^files/calendar\.ics$ https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/XXXXXXX/calendar.ics [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: I decided to go with a simple:
Redirect 303 /files/calendar.ics https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/XXXXXXX/calendar.ics

I found that the redirect it logged in apache's access log just fine. I haven't found a way to customise AWStats to parse this and display the information I want. I'm looking into writing a script (preferably bash) to parse it - count #redirects of calendar.ics & count #redirects from unique IPs.

Comment: Yes you can use `Redirect` directive also but it doesn't give power of `RewriteRule` for ex. `/files/Calendar.ics` won't be handled by Redirect since there is capital C.